# Keras Tensor get name

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras

I've a list of keras tensors, and for every one I provide a name with `name` parameter.
For example, I want to name BatchNormalization `layer` as `"a"`:

```py
layer = BatchNormalization(axis=3, name="a")(input)
```

But when I try to retrieve the name I gave to the level, it looks like this:

```py
print(layer.name)
>>> a_2/cond/Merge:0
```

How can I retrieve the exact name I've given my `layer` object (`"a"` for this example) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's separate this line into two lines:

```
layer = BatchNormalization(axis=3, name="a")
node = layer(input)
```

Now if you tried to output

```
layer.name
```

it will be "a".

What were you trying to do is outputting the name of the output tensor of this batchnorm layer which is basicaly a tensorflow tensor that results from this merge operation.

So to do this you have to do it to the layer as shown above or do some processing to the operation name as it will always contain the layer name in it.

Answer (score 1):

I know the question has been answered but the update of the question have erase an issue that the author had pointed out so i ll write my answer anyway for the people that will come next.

Like OP i create a layer (which will be a dense one here):

```
>>> l = Dense(20,activation='softmax',name='a')
>>> l.name
a
```

if i re run this code in the same console i get the same results. **However** when i run the code of the question:

```
>>> l = Dense(20,activation='softmax',name='a')(inputs)
>>> l.name
a/Softmax:0
```

and when i re run the code:

```
>>> l = Dense(20,activation='softmax',name='a')(inputs)
>>> l.name
a_1/Softmax:0
```

and if i change it a little:

```
>>> l = Dense(20,activation='softmax',name='a')(l)
>>> l.name
a_2/Softmax:0
```

**SO** Be careful when creating layers: You are creating an independent layer or a tensor resulting from the calculus (as stated in the accepted answer)

You can retrieve the name by a simple split **But** only the first time you instanciate the network. In case of a rerun (new instance) the names will change!

Answer (score -1):

You can do

```
[layer.name for layer in model.layers]
```

This will output a list of all layer names. 
Or it can be retrieved from model.

```
model.get_layer('a').name
```

Comment: the question is about the change of name when the code is rerun. As stated in the question, evaleria knows how to get the name of a layer..

Comment: @Alexis, could you please clarify you comment and downvote? It has nothing to do with re run, isn't it